# Autocomplete combobox with drop list property

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to implement an auto-complete combo box in C#.I could do this when i set the combo box drop down property to 'drop down'.But couldn't get the result when drop down property is set to 'Drop list'. Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code :

```
var connection=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            var command=new SqlCommand("SELECT model FROM vehicle",connection);
            var adapter=new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                col.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["model"].ToString());
            }
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection combData = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            getData(combData);
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = combData;
        }
        private void getData(AutoCompleteStringCollection dataCollection)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connetionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            string sql = "SELECT model FROM vehicle";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                adapter.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    dataCollection.Add(row[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: But how come we type in droplist?

Comment: @utility ComboBox displays a text box combined with a ListBox, which enables the user to select items from the list or enter new values.

Comment: If im not mistaken OP wants to change the style of dropdown but he is worried if he changes to dropdown others can edit them and save directly.You have not added his funtionality